# Get Perspective Transformation for crooked rectangle

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, rectangles, perspective

How do I get perspective tranformation for crooked (hand-drawn) rectangle?

That's what I want:

[image]

But instead I got:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
Rect boundingBox(boundingRect(countours[largest_contour_index]));

vector<Point> not_a_rect_shape;
not_a_rect_shape.push_back(boundingBox.tl());
not_a_rect_shape.push_back(Point(boundingBox.tl().x, boundingBox.br().y));
not_a_rect_shape.push_back(boundingBox.br());
not_a_rect_shape.push_back(Point(boundingBox.br().x, boundingBox.tl().y));

RotatedRect box = minAreaRect(cv::Mat(not_a_rect_shape));

Point2f pts[4];
box.points(pts);

cv::Point2f src_vertices[4];
src_vertices[0] = not_a_rect_shape[0];
src_vertices[1] = not_a_rect_shape[1];
src_vertices[2] = not_a_rect_shape[3];
src_vertices[3] = not_a_rect_shape[2];

Point2f dst_vertices[4];
dst_vertices[0] = Point(0, 0);
dst_vertices[1] = Point(box.boundingRect().width-1, 0);
dst_vertices[2] = Point(0, box.boundingRect().height-1);
dst_vertices[3] = Point(box.boundingRect().width-1, box.boundingRect().height-1);

Mat warpAffineMatrix = getAffineTransform(src_vertices, dst_vertices);

cv::Mat rotated;
cv::Size size(box.boundingRect().width, box.boundingRect().height);
warpAffine(src, rotated, warpAffineMatrix, size, INTER_LINEAR, BORDER_CONSTANT);

imshow("rotated.jpg", rotated);
```

P.S. All rectangles that I worked with are hand drawn. Maybe, is it working only for straight rectangles?

Comment: You should provide four corners of your quadlateral instead of boundingbox.

Comment: I tried it. It also doesn't work

Comment: It worked when I tried. So I guess something else is wrong in your part.

Comment: Did you try for hand-drawn rectangle?

Comment: You are right. I did stupid mistake. Thank you

Comment: Please share your mistake and your solution so other people can avoid that mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using Affine Transforms for a **perspective** problem. The affine transform only models rotation, translation and scaling (both vertical and horizontal), so your problem cannot be solved using this kind of transform. Use perspective transform instead.

EDIT: Hey, look at [this nice tutorial](http://opencv-code.com/tutorials/automatic-perspective-correction-for-quadrilateral-objects/) using `cv::getPerspectiveTransform` and `cv::WarpPerspective`, also using 4 corners as in your scenario. It may solve your problem!

Comment: Ok, that's weird. How can two different approaches (affine and perspective transformations) can give you the same result? Maybe there is another problem.. Still: **don't use affine transformation**, is not what you want, trust me ;)

Comment: Need to changes: (1 using cv::getPerspectiveTransform and cv::WarpPerspective and (2 provide four corners of your quadlateral instead of boundingbox

Comment: Are we? Did it finally work? feel free to upvote if it helped you.. heheh ;)

Comment: If you are interested in those kind of transforms and the difference between them, there is plenty of documentation out there.. http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/HIPR2/affine.htm